# How to get session variables in wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi iam new to wordpress and I have created a plugin at which I need to print all the session data.First I have created a file in plugin folder and added code like

```
function myplugin_classname() {
    print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

And I put an click event for two button with class `tags` like

```
$('.tags').on('click',function(){
     $.post('my_page.php',{val:$(this).val()});
});
```

and in my_page.php I kept like

```
$_SESSION['tag'] = $_POST['val'];
```

but when it comes to printing the session variables at `myplugin_classname` (by refreshing the page)it doesnt prints the **newly assigned session variable**....How to solve this..??I have started session through `theme-my-login` login.

Comment: do you have `session_start()`? in your `my_page.php`

Comment: Actually if I put session_start() it will be working but if I logged out it still shows the session variable that initialized from that page

Comment: you might need to tweak the wp_logout, it maybe unsetting the variables rather than doing a session_destroy()

Comment: where I can do that..@DevZer0..??

Comment: May be its problem with theme-my-login plugin..??

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0 look for wp_logout, its calling 2 more functions so it could be buried deep

Comment: also this might come in handy http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-does-wordpress-handle-sessions-and-session-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `<?php session_start(); ?>` at beginning of my_page.php

After that for destroying session you can use wp_logout action in wordpress. code is as follows

```
<?php function custom_unset_session() {
   // your code 
   unset($_SESSION['tag']);
} 
add_action('wp_logout', 'custom_unset_session');
?>
```

Comment: Actually if I put session_start() it will be working but if I logged out it still shows the session variable that initialized from that page

Comment: then unset session variable at the time of logout. you can use following code and add this code in you theme functions.php file.

`<?php
function custom_unset_session() {
    // your code
    unset($_SESSION['tag']);
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'custom_unset_session');
?>`

Comment: Then how to unset the session..??unset($_SESSION)..??

Comment: using the following code

`<?php function custom_unset_session() { // your code unset($_SESSION['tag']); } add_action('wp_logout', 'custom_unset_session'); ?> `

Comment: ....This is awsome....please update your ans with the above coment,then if any other want the same they get benifit

Answer (score 2):

```
// On your plugin  functions.php
function register_session() {
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
}

add_action('init', 'register_session');

function your_function() {
    //Here you can unset your session variabl
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function');
//Now you can use
$_SESSION['tag'] = $_POST['val'];
```

Comment: Actually if I put session_start() it will be working but if I logged out it still shows the session variable that initialized from that page

Comment: Now you can see i have add function for logout

Answer (score 0):

Those two articles are helpful as well:

http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress/

http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/